# firestore/permission-denied error with Firestore query immediately after signInAnonymously completes successfully

Tags: javascript, react-native, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication, firebase-security

i'm trying to get/write and update data in firestore in react native (0.66.3), Showing error

> [Error: [firestore/permission-denied] The caller does not have permission to execute the specified operation.]

[image: DB]

i update rules also

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
match /databases/{database}/documents {
 match /{document=**} {
  allow read, write: if request.auth != null;
  }
 }
}
```

App code

```
import React from 'react';
import { Text, View, TouchableOpacity } from 'react-native';

import firestore from '@react-native-firebase/firestore';
import auth from '@react-native-firebase/auth';


export default function App() {
  async function addTodo() {
    await auth().signInAnonymously().then((res)=> {
      console.log(auth().currentUser.uid);
      return firestore().collection('document').get();
    }).catch((err)=>{
      console.log(err);
    }); 
  }
 
  return (
    <View>
      <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => addTodo()} style={{padding:50}}>
        <Text>Test </Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
    </View>
  );
}
```

Output [image]

Comment: Can you `console.log(currentUserUID)` right before the query and check if user is actually logged in ?

Comment: @Dharmaraj Yes i tries with anonymous user `await auth().signInAnonymously().then(()=> {       return firestore().collection('users').get();     }).catch((err)=>{       console.log(err);     });`

Comment: Use an auth state listener to know when the user is fully signed in and ready to make requests.  It's discussed a the top of the docs: https://rnfirebase.io/auth/usage#listening-to-authentication-state

Comment: If you `console.log(auth().currentUser.uid)` right before the call to `return firestore().collection('users').get();`, what does it output?

Comment: @DougStevenson i logged with anonymous user, but showing same error

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen then showing same error `The caller does not have permission to execute the specified operation`

Comment: That's not the output from the `console.log` statement. Please show us what the new `console.log(auth().currentUser.uid)` outputs.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen showing uid (`SFeAHnACfDTEUVRFPD26HqPAvi53`) when i print `console.log(auth().currentUser.uid)`

Comment: Please edit your question (there's a link right under it) to show both the updated code, and its output.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen i update code in question. please check

Comment: Interesting, so it's probably not the authentication state causing the rejection. Did you enable App Check for your Firestore database by any chance?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen i update DB rules in firebase to `allow read, write:` but same error showing

Comment: That makes no difference when App Check is enabled, which is why I asked about that in my previous comment.